# How to correct a JavaScript/jQuery lookahead regex for an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am writing a JavaScript/jQuery function that inserts a line break when it detects either a period "." or a close parenthesis ")" at the end of a line.  I decided that I could use a regex for this, but I am stuck.  At first, the function would insert a break without fail when it encountered either character and that was almost what I wanted, so I added an if statement to further control the function.
If the period is followed by a parenthesis, then it should break after the close parenthesis instead of the period.  However, I need to specify a second regex for this if statement, which is where I'm stuck.

How do I write a negative lookahead regex that will match a period "." when it is not followed by a space and an open parenthesis "(" ?

The below function is what I have currently:
I get an "Invalid regular expression" error in console over the if statement, /\.\(\).(?!()/g.
It also says there is an "Unterminated group" but I'm not sure where that is in my expression.

```
$(‘.classItem’).each(function(i) {
    var oldString = $(this).html();

    if( /\.\(\).(?!()/g.test(oldString) == true ) //<— If the string has a period that is not followed by a space and an open parenthesis
    {
        newString = oldString.replace(/(\.\s+)/g, "$1 <br>");  //<— Then break at the period if true.
        $(‘.classItem’).html(newString);
    }
    else
    {
        newString = oldString.replace(/(\)\s+)/g, "$1 <br>");  //<— Then break at the close parenthesis if false.
        $(‘.classItem’).html(newString);
    }
});
```

In the end I want this function to help format text to look like this:
“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec consectetur nibh non hendrerit interdum. (elit)
Nulla eget sem vulputate, ultrices nunc vel, rutrum leo. (ipsum)
Vestibulum pharetra orci eu ante aliquam, ac molestie libero placerat.“

Before I added the if statement, it was causing this:
“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec consectetur nibh non hendrerit interdum.
(elit)
Nulla eget sem vulputate, ultrices nunc vel, rutrum leo.
(ipsum)
Vestibulum pharetra orci eu ante aliquam, ac molestie libero placerat.“

Comment: To *match a period "." when it is not followed by a space and an open parenthesis "("* you may use `/\.(?![\s(])/g`. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it does help and it answers my specific question.  Thank you.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer below? It seems to do something different

Comment: I tried both yours and the other user's regex and both worked in my function with no visible difference to me.  I accepted because my question was answered for the most part.  If it does something different, then maybe I wrote my regex wrong and I don't see it.  Can you clarify what it does differently?

My function actually still doesn't work entirely as I want it, but I think my if statement is to blame and I should save it for a separate post.

Comment: `\.\(\).(?!\()` matches `.()` and then any char but a line break char not followed with `(`. My suggestion does what you asked: *a period "." when it is not followed by a space and an open parenthesis "("*, note: when followed *immediately* by either whitespace or `(`

Answer (score 0):

You missed backward slash in RegExp:

```
/\.\(\).(?!()/g
```

Correct it:

```
/\.\(\).(?!\()/g
```

```js
$('.classItem').each(function(i) {
var oldString = $(this).html();

if( /\.\(\).(?!\()/g.test(oldString) == true ) //<— If the string has a period that is not followed by a space and an open parenthesis
{
    newString = oldString.replace(/(\.\s+)/g, "$1 <br>");  //<— Then break at the period if true.
    $('.classItem').html(newString);
}
else
{
    newString = oldString.replace(/(\)\s+)/g, "$1 <br>");  //<— Then break at the close parenthesis if false.
    $('.classItem').html(newString);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classItem">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec consectetur nibh non hendrerit interdum.
(elit)
Nulla eget sem vulputate, ultrices nunc vel, rutrum leo.
(ipsum)
Vestibulum pharetra orci eu ante aliquam, ac molestie libero placerat.
</div>
```

Comment: Is it that I need to escape the open parenthesis again in the lookahead even though I escaped it once already?

Answer (score 0):

Through the use of regexr.com and more research I ended up with a regex that better answered my question.  I found that it’s possible to use multiple negative lookahead groups in a single expression.  This gave me a little more freedom to be more precise in the overall expression instead of hoping I could catch all the logic in a single group.

The regex that worked the best to answer my question was:
`/\.(?!\()(?!\s\()/g`
See here: https://regexr.com/4p94m

The first negative lookahead `(?!\()`, matches when the period is not followed by a close parenthesis.  This group eliminates matching an .() case, which the second group doesn't catch on its own.
The second negative lookahead `(?!\s\()`, matches when the period is not followed by a whitespace character and the close parenthesis.
When used together, this makes the regex more specific and allows it to skip cases such as: .(), . (), and
._____(), a tab whitespace.  Any further cases can be resolved by adding another negative lookahead group.

(`(?!\s\()`, derived from `/\.(?![\s(])/g`, an answer by Wiktor Stribiżew in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839415/how-to-correct-a-javascript-jquery-lookahead-regex-for-an-if-statement#comment103954043_58839415))